# Tendermint access leveldb via node

Tags: go, rpc, json-rpc, leveldb, tendermint

I have a sample go application running with tendermint. I would like to access the data Tendermint's blockchain stores in leveldb while both the application and the node are running.

I have tried to run a basic go script that iterates over the tx_index.db which stores the tx.hash and the corresponding result of every transaction. But when I try to run the script the program panics with an error message.

Here's the go script to iterate over the tx_index.db

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb"
)

func main() {
    db, err := leveldb.OpenFile("tx_index.db", nil)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    iter := db.NewIterator(nil, nil)
    for iter.Next() {
        key := iter.Key()
        h_key := fmt.Sprintf("%X", key)
        value := iter.Value()
        h_value := fmt.Sprintf("%X", value)
        fmt.Printf("Key: %v \nValue: %v \n", h_key, h_value)
    }
    iter.Release()
    err = iter.Error()
    defer db.Close()

}
```

Upon running the above script while the application and the tendermint node are running. I get the following error message!

```
panic: resource temporarily unavailable

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.main()
    $HOME/tendermint/data/read_db.go:11 +0x375
exit status 2
```

I am interested in accessing the tx_index.db while the application and tendermint node are running to get the transaction hash of the transactions performed.

PS: If it's feasible I'd like to know if there's a way to get tx.hash by accessing the tx_index.db by interacting with the tendermint node.

Comment: I don't think you can access the same db. But you can make a copy and use it. Or better use RPC https://tendermint.com/rpc/ to get data you desire.

Comment: Can a copy of the db get updated in parallel with the original db tendermint would access. Is it possible for the original db to be connected with both tendermint and the copy.

Comment: I am trying to make us the tendermint.com/rpc 'Subscribe' method but the docs don't provide any example and I'm unable to understand how to run the method. I could run other rpc endpoints referring the examples.